# JQUERY get the value of a dynamically added span element when the sibling span clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a scenario where i can not use `button` , so i used a `span` as a button .

```
let prodState = [];
function populateProductState(tag) {
    $(".product-state-tags").empty();
    prodState.forEach((tag) => {
        if (tag.trim() !== "") {
            $("ul.product-state-tags").append(`
            <li>
                <span class="delete-tag">x</span>
                <span class="tag-value">${tag}</span>
            </li>
        `);
        }
    });
    $(".product-state-input").val("");
}

$(".product-state-input").on("keypress", function (e) {
    var keycode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;
    if (keycode == "13") {
        e.preventDefault();

        const v = e.target.value.trim();
        if (v !== "") {
            prodState.push(v.trim());
        }

        populateProductState(v);
        console.log(prodState);
    }
});

// del tag
$("body").on("click", ".delete-tag", (e) => {
    const v = $(this).closest("span.tag-value").text();
    console.log(v);
});
```

the last `console.log` gives nothing where I want the inside text.

Comment: Change `this` to `e.currentTarget`. Arrow functions don't receive the target element as `this`.

Comment: same result - nothing

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: There is no closest `.tag-value` from `.delete-tag`. `.closest()` looks for a containing element, not a sibling. You want `$(e.target).next().text()`

Comment: thx @Barmar this works please add an answer to accept